# Rotating Android GridView with Items

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-gridview

I was wondering whats the best way to rotate a GridView with the scrollbar also changing orientation when a user rotates their screen. The rotation example of what I want to accomplish:

```
Portrait
| Part 1 | Part 2 |
-------------------
|   5    |   6    | |
|   4    |   3    | |
|   2    |   4    | V
|   5    |   1    |


Landscape
------------------------------- 
Part 1 |  5 |   4 |  2  |  5  |
--------------------------------
Part 2 |  6 |   3 |  4  |  1  |

--->
```

I couldn't find any android/java libraries that could accomplish this. Maybe I need to use the Matrix object to do some rotation manipulation? Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice tutorial that demonstrates what you are looking for. Here is the link: 
http://spragucm.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/android-horizontal-and-vertical-gridview-tutorial/
I hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like the right step in right direction. Just need to figure out the resizing of images for gridview items.